# Brower(Chrome) crash while loading large GeoJson file to google map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

My GeoJson file size is 200MB
I want to load the data of this GeoJson file in google map
But while loading my browser (Chrome)  crash while loading this file data

Here is my code which I have used in html file

```
function initialize() {
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
            zoom: 7,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.3555, 1.1743),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // SATELLITE, ROADMAP, HYBRID
        });

        map.data.loadGeoJson('filename');       
    }
```

Comment: It's bad practise to inject large files into a browser. It would be much more advisable to split your file into chunks and load them when they're needed, for example when zooming in or moving around at a specific zoom level.

Comment: What device/operating system?  Probably running out of memory.